# How to get all links in a webpage using perl?

Tags: perl, html-parsing, web-scraping

I want to get all links `(<a href='http://.*')` from a web page using perl, which module should I use? Or just use regex myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize) to get the web page?
If yes then you can use the function [$mech->links()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize#$mech-%3Elinks%28%29) which is in that module to get all the links.

Comment: I'm using LWP, but it does not matter. Which is faster? I need speed.

Comment: I havent used LWP. I havent used it so extensively so i cant comment on speed.

Comment: @everbox - [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) is subclass of `LWP::UserAgent`, so it should be essentially the same speed.